# pair different elements in a list depending on their quantity

Tags: c#

```
//Streamwriter object used to create the text file
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Tarek_Akkawi\Desktop\SynmaticsInputFile.txt");

        //WriteLine used instead of Write in order to introduce a new line for each person
        sw.WriteLine("lucas 8 4 5");
        sw.WriteLine("lucas 8");
        sw.WriteLine("Alex 1 2 3");
        sw.WriteLine("Alex 4 22 4");
        sw.WriteLine("nia 22 3");
        sw.WriteLine("nia 2 3");


        sw.Close();




        OuputLogic opl = new OuputLogic();


public class OuputLogic
{

    public OuputLogic()
    {
        //using constructor to initialize the new file
        Pair();
    }

    //Using streamread class to read the file
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Tarek_Akkawi\Desktop\SynmaticsInputFile.txt");

    //Method to read text file
    public string ReadFile()
    {
        string x = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return x;

    }


    //Method To manipulate TExt file
    public void Pair()
    {

        List<string> getdata = ReadFile().Trim().Split().ToList();


        var tuples = getdata.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).Zip(getdata.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1), (a, b) => new Tuple<string, string>(a, b)).ToArray();
```

So I'm trying to pair my items in my list based on the quantity of numbers each name has. So the idea would be i want to pair lucas with 8 4 5 then lucas with 8 etc etc. 
Based on the research I've done the closest i came to achieving that was through the tuple above but it pairs based on the modulo's result. 
I'm looking for something that would allow the pairing of each name that has any number of figures across it.

Comment: Do you want to concatenate each of the finding for a name, e.g. Alex would have  1 2 3 4 22 ?

Comment: Use either Dictionary<string,List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> or Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> or Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>

Comment: Ideally i would want to get the number at the correspondant position an add it. So if for example alex has numbers 1 2 3 and 4 22 4 then i would want alex 5 24 7.  I was thinking to pair each name with their figures , convert to integer the numbera so i can do the additiin and then return the result i want

Comment: I will try using dictionary or keyvalue pair and see how it plays out.